# In gradle, how can I get the url of a file I just uploaded to nexus?

Tags: gradle, build, nexus

I have a gradle job that uploads an artifact to maven.

Here's the standard boilerplate:

```
uploadArchives {
   repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'http://nexus-host/nexus/content/releases/') {
                authentication(userName: System.getenv('RELEASE_USER'), password: System.getenv('RELEASE_PWD'));
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://nexus-host/nexus/content/snapshots/') {
                authentication(userName: System.getenv('SNAPSHOT_USER'), password: System.getenv('SNAPSHOT_PWD'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then I run it with:

```
./gradlew uploadArchives
```

I want to write the url of the uploaded file into a file called `.artifact_url`, but I'm having a difficult time finding documentation to help me find out how to get that url so I can write it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this could be done via an [ArtifactResolutionQuery](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.query.ArtifactResolutionQuery.html)

Comment: That seems to get me where it is installed on my machine, because it comes back with DefaultResolvedArtifactResult.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to call the nexus rest api

eg [/artifact/maven/redirect](https://oss.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/path__artifact_maven_redirect.html)

Comment: This is the answer I used, but it's not an answer to the question I asked.

Comment: Worthy of an upvote then? Perhaps your answer is somewhere in [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/deployer)